# How to access projected 3d tracks of the camera solver?

Tags: python, camera, constraints, tracking

For further reconstruction of a shot, I'd like to access the 3d location of the **projected tracks by the camera solver constraint** in the *3d View* for all frames via python.

While searching through the *Datablocks* I've only found a read only [`bundle`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack.html?highlight=bundle#bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack.bundle) attribute per track: `bpy.data.movieclips["clip_name"].tracking.tracks["track_name"].bundle`, but unfortunately the given coordinates are totally off:

[image]

Is there any way to access the properties of the 3d tracks at the moment?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy matrix_world uninfluenced by "Camera Solver" constraint, ie set constraint influence to 0, set the frame to the first frame of the simulation,  save a matrix_world copy, then reset the influence.

The track positions are `mworldcopy * Track.bundle`

Camera tracking points in red, object tracking points in green, resultant object tracking points in yellow.

```
import bpy

from sound_drivers.BGL_draw_visualiser import BGLWidget

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
scene.frame_set(1)
camera = cam = scene.camera
cam_const = cam.constraints[0]
cam_const.influence = 0
mw = cam.matrix_world.copy()
cam_const.influence = 1

class ShowTracks(BGLWidget):
    def draw_region(self, context):
        clip = context.scene.active_clip
        tracking = clip.tracking                
        tracking_object = clip.tracking.objects.active

        # match to object tracking
        # from bl_operators/clip.py
        if camera:
            reconstruction = tracking_object.reconstruction
            framenr = scene.frame_current - clip.frame_start + 1
            reconstructed_matrix = reconstruction.cameras.matrix_from_frame(framenr)
            matrix = camera.matrix_world * reconstructed_matrix.inverted()

        else:
            return

        tracks = tracking.objects

        # track points in global space current frame         
        pts = [matrix  * t.bundle for t in tracks['Object'].tracks]    
        pts = self.points3d_points2d(context, pts)
        self.draw_points(pts, lw=2, color=(1, 1, 0, 1))

        # tracking data 
        pts = [mw * t.bundle for t in tracks['Camera'].tracks]
        pts = self.points3d_points2d(context, pts)
        self.draw_points(pts, lw=1, color=(1, 0, 0, 1))

        pts = [mw * t.bundle for t in tracks['Object'].tracks]
        pts = self.points3d_points2d(context, pts)
        self.draw_points(pts, lw=1, color=(0, 1, 0, 1))

v = ShowTracks(None, bpy.context, bpy.types.SpaceView3D)
```

[image]

Comment: Found code required in bl_operators/clip.py, fortunately cos the source code had me a bit stumped on what is readily available thru the API with `reconstruction.cameras.matrix_from_frame(framenr)`  Edited the answer to show yellow lines connecting the solved object tracks, in the same locations as empties created with bpy.ops.track_to_empty and setting the generated empty's constraint `use_3d_position` to True would be.